# Take formula and set array to a named range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having difficulty finding details online since my searches lead to arrays in VBA but not array use on a worksheet

1) I essentially want to take a formula I have on one sheet

2) copy it

3) select a named range

4) set the function as an array to the named range area.

In my VBA I was paste special formulas but that was adding copying / pasting the same formula as separate areas in each cell.  I just want one big array

Note: I'm not at all familiar with VBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

1. I changed the formula to be text by adding `'` at the start of the
   formula
2. I then set a variable to `RefersToRange.value`
3. then `RefersToRange.FormulaArray`

I wasn't aware of #3 but yeah all good now.